# Oculta el botón flotante al contraer la toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo un `FloatingActionButton` anclado a la parte inferior de una imagen que esta dentro de la `CollapsingToolbarLayout` y quiero que cuando se contrae la barra se oculte el botón flotante.

Si asigno el anclaje al `AppBarLayout` automáticamente lo hace, pero cuando cambio el anclaje en el `ImageView` ya que debajo de la imagen tengo más contenido (similar a la ficha de google maps) pues al contraer del todo la toolbar sigue mostrándose.

Comment: muestra una parte del codigo amigo